# Adding new column for different rows based on the values present in the same row for a different column

Tags: r, conditional-statements, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe with different combination of factors. each factor is presented in its column (see below)

```
F1   F2   F3   F4
1     1
1          1  
1                1
```

I want to add a new column at the end like below

```
F1   F2   F3   F4  trt
1    1             F1_F2
1          1       F1_F3
1               1  F1_F4
```

How do I create this column with conditional merging in R. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you share your sample data with `dput()` so we can copy/paste it and see all the relevant data structure information? `dput(your_data)`. That will answer important questions like, what class are your columns? What is in the cells you show as blank, empty strings, `NA` or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
aggregate(ind~row, na.omit(cbind(row = c(row(df)), stack(df))), paste, collapse = "_")
  row   ind
1   1 F1_F2
2   2 F1_F3
3   3 F1_F4
```

---

```
df <- structure(list(F1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), F2 = c(1L, NA, NA), F3 = c(NA, 
1L, NA), F4 = c(NA, NA, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution utilizes `dplyr::mutate` in combination with `dplyr::across` to replace all `1` values with the column name. `tidyr::unite()` can then be used to create the `trt` column.

```r
library(tidyverse)

tibble(
  F1 = rep(1, 3),
  F2 = c(1, 0, 0),
  F3 = c(0, 1, 0),
  F4 = c(0, 0, 1),
) |>
  mutate(across(everything(),
                \(x) ifelse(x == 1, cur_column(), NA))) |>
  unite("trt", remove = FALSE, na.rm = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   trt   F1    F2    F3    F4   
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 F1_F2 F1    F2    <NA>  <NA> 
#> 2 F1_F3 F1    <NA>  F3    <NA> 
#> 3 F1_F4 F1    <NA>  <NA>  F4
```